# camera view alingment to show user perspective

Tags: camera

[image: my user perspective]I am new to blender. I am trying to build a 3d plane game. The attached picture is my user perspective. I want to make the camera view everything inside the red box. How do i do that? Also my sky dome is not showing in my camera view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad 0</kbd> to move the camera to the current perspective view.

   2. Select the sky dome, change to edit mode and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces, next press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shit</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to flip normals to inside.